# Swift method that takes either String or Substring as parameter

Tags: swift, string, substring

I've been trying to learn how the new Swift 4 Strings and Substrings work.

Since most of what you can do to a String you can also do to a Substring, I was trying to find a way to combine the following two methods into one:

```
static func isConsonant(ipa: String) -> Bool {
    return "ptkʧfθsʃbdgʤvðzʒmnŋlwjhrʔɾ".contains(ipa)
}

static func isConsonant(ipa: Substring) -> Bool {
    return "ptkʧfθsʃbdgʤvðzʒmnŋlwjhrʔɾ".contains(ipa)
}
```

I thought I recall reading something about `StringProtocol` being the link, but this doesn't work:

```
static func isConsonant(ipa: StringProtocol) -> Bool {
    return "ptkʧfθsʃbdgʤvðzʒmnŋlwjhrʔɾ".contains(ipa)
}
```

with the error being

> Protocol 'StringProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is there a parameter type that would accept either `String` or `Substring`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it *generic*

```
func isConsonant<T>(ipa: T) -> Bool where T: StringProtocol {
    return "ptkʧfθsʃbdgʤvðzʒmnŋlwjhrʔɾ".contains(ipa)
}
```

in the same way as other [`StringProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol)
methods, such as

```
func contains<T>(_ other: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol
func appending<T>(_ aString: T) -> String where T : StringProtocol
// ...
```

You *could* also make it an extension method or property of `StringProtocol`

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isConsonant: Bool {
        return "ptkʧfθsʃbdgʤvðzʒmnŋlwjhrʔɾ".contains(self)
    }
}
```

but that bears the danger of name conflicts with other frameworks.

Comment: Aside question: I checked [swift docs](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/) and didn't find the `StringProtocol` protocol (because it is a part of Swift 4...), I found [StringProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol), but how can I even know about its existence? should I check proposals? please advice

Comment: @AhmadF: https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-0-released/ is a good overview, with a link to ["SE-0163 String Revision: Collection Conformance, C Interop, Transcoding"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md). – Also: https://github.com/ole/whats-new-in-swift-4